# JavaScript - How to use variable data parsed into PHP?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I have a form that has data that is parsed to a PHP file. I was wondering how to use the data that is also sent in the variable `myData`. If the form serializes then I can use the `$_GET['add_album']`, but how do I use `myData` in PHP? I want to echo the data in my PHP file. Here is my AJAX:

```
var div = document.getElementById("hidden_div");
                    var myData = div.textContent;
                    /*var pathh = '<?php echo $pathh ?>';*/
                    alert(JavaScriptAlert); 
                    $.ajax
                    (
                        {
                            url:"add_album.php",
                            type: "GET",
                            data: {myData: myData, form: $('#form3').serialize()}, 
                            success:function(result)
                            {
                                alert(result);
                            }
                        }
                    );
```

and my PHP:

```
<?php
echo myData.'\\'$_GET['add_album']; //need to echo out the data inside the "myData" variable
mkdir(myData.'\\'$_GET['add_album']);
?>
```

Comment: It is like you have the `add_album` but change the index to `myData`.

Comment: I don't understand your meaning. What do you mean by index?

Comment: missing concatenate operator "."

Comment: Where am I missing the concatenate operator "."?

Comment: `echo myData.'\\'.$_GET['add_album'];` , ditto mkdir you should be getting syntax errors, but may not see them

Comment: The index is the value between the `[]`. `$_GET['myData']` should have the value the JS is sending.

Comment: `user3783243` shouldn't that be $_GET['form'] then? You see, myData contains a path which is like `C:\\wamp64\code\username\` and $_GET['add_album'] contains the text from the user's serialised form, i.e. it contains the text that the user inputted which is the name of a new folder.

Comment: Oh wait so, I might be able to do this: `echo $_GET['myData'].'\\'$_GET['add_album'];` ??

Comment: Yes, that should work. You can always do `print_r($_GET)` and it will display all the data that was sent. From there you will now what indexs are available.

Answer (score 1):

`data` "is converted to a query string, if not already a string."

Usually, to send form data, you'd use `data: $('#form3').serialize()`. You have `{myData: myData, form: $('#form3').serialize()}` though, which gets converted to

```
myData=some_divtext&form=serialized_form_content
```

Which means on the server, you now have `$_GET['myData']` and `$_GET['form']`

I don't think that's what you want, mostly because you'd have to manually parse the form query string, therefore my suggestion would be

1. add `<input name="mydata" type="hidden">` to your form
2. instead of

   ```
   var div = document.getElementById("hidden_div");
   var myData = div.textContent;
   ```

   use

   ```
   $('#form3 [name=mydata]').val($('#hidden_div').text());
   ```
3. send `data: $('#form3').serialize()`